# 405 error while using http get method in angular

Tags: angular, get, http-get

I have an api at the back end to do paging and I am calling it in frontend service using http get method but getting 405 error.Pls let me know what is wrong in the getGiftCards().

```
public class Paging
    {
        const int maxPageSize = 50;
        public int pageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
        public int _pageSize { get; set; } = 50;
        public int pageSize
        {
            get { return _pageSize; }
            set
            {
                _pageSize = (value > maxPageSize) ? maxPageSize : value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Repository

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<GiftCard>> GetByCompanyId(string companyId, [FromQuery] Paging paging)
           {

                     // Return List of Giftcard  
                   var source = await _context.DbCollection
                    .Find(GiftCard => GiftCard.CompanyId == companyId)
                    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                  //  return PaginatedResponse<GiftCard>.ToPagedList(source, paging.pageNumber, paging.pageSize);
                       
            // Get's No of Rows Count   
            int count = source.Count;

                 // Parameter is passed from Query string if it is null then it default Value will be pageNumber:1  
                 int CurrentPage = paging.pageNumber;

                 // Parameter is passed from Query string if it is null then it default Value will be pageSize:50  
                 int PageSize = paging.pageSize;

                 // Display TotalCount to Records to User  
                 int TotalCount = count;

                 // Calculating Totalpage by Dividing (No of Records / Pagesize)  
                 int TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)PageSize);

                 // Returns List of Giftcard after applying Paging   
                 var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();

                 // if CurrentPage is greater than 1 means it has previousPage  
                 var previousPage = CurrentPage > 1 ? "Yes" : "No";

                 // if TotalPages is greater than CurrentPage means it has nextPage  
                 var nextPage = CurrentPage < TotalPages ? "Yes" : "No";

                 // Object which we are going to send in header   
                 var paginationMetadata = new
                 {
                     totalCount = TotalCount,
                     pageSize = PageSize,
                     currentPage = CurrentPage,
                     totalPages = TotalPages,
                     previousPage,
                     nextPage
                 };

              // Setting Header  
              // Response.Headers.Add("Paging-Headers", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationMetadata));
                 // Returing List of Giftcard Collections  
                 return items; 


        }
```

Controller

```
   [Route("[action]/{Companyid}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<GiftCard>>> GetByCompanyId(string Companyid, [FromQuery] Paging paging)
    {                 
    return Ok(await _GiftCardRepository.GetByCompanyId(Companyid,paging).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
```

Front end Service

```
 getGiftCards(): Promise<any> {   
    return this.http
      .get<GiftCard[]>(this.ApiBaseUrl + "/GiftCard/GetByCompanyId/all?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50")
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler)).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: Can you check the endpoint from browser to tools like Postman?

Comment: In the post man it works.The problem is in front end